# Dividir una matriz por la otra sobre fechas

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Tengo una base de datos de los pagos mensuales a una plataforma que se han inicializado `orders.engagement = 'R'` o que ya son mensuales `orders.engagement = 'M'`, (donde pueden ver un MySQL Fiddle luego en la pregunta). Actualmente, alrededor de 74% de las iniciaciones se han convertido en pagos mensuales. Me gustaría saber cuál es esta tasa mensualmente porque en los ultimos meses solo obtengo 45%:

Entonces, quiero calcular el SQL que calcula la relación entre:

```
Número de iniciaciones que dieron lugar a al menos un pago en los meses siguientes
---- dividida ----
Número de iniciaciones
```

Quiero hacer esta proporción para cada mez. Pero en las siguientes pruebas, creo que cuando hago mi GROUP BY por mes pierdo el "al menos un pago en los meses siguientes"

Esto es lo que hizo para devuelver el número de iniciaciones que dieron lugar a al menos un pago en los meses siguientes:

```
SELECT orders_2.date, COUNT(DISTINCT orders_2.`gxo_vads_subscription`) count_first_recurrent
    FROM `orders` AS orders_2
    INNER JOIN `orders` AS orders_1 ON orders_2.`gxo_vads_subscription` = orders_1.`gxo_vads_subscription`
    # Donde la transacion a logrado
    WHERE orders_2.status = 2
        AND orders_2.`engagement` = 'R'
        AND orders_2.`gxo_means` = 'CB'
        AND orders_1.`engagement` = 'M'
        AND orders_2.date >= orders_1.date + INTERVAL 30 DAY
GROUP BY YEAR(orders_2.date), MONTH(orders_2.date)
```

Me devuelve:

```
...
25/5/2021, 1:10    2 651
7/6/2021, 1:10     2 443
```

[aqui esta el Fiddle relacionado con un extracto de la base de datos](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed044f1/1/0)

Y esto es todas las transacciones inicializadas cada mez:

```sql
SELECT orders_3.date, COUNT(DISTINCT orders_3.`gxo_vads_subscription`) count_initialization
        FROM `orders` AS orders_3
        -- INNER JOIN `orders` AS orders_4 ON orders_3.`gxo_vads_subscription` = orders_4.`gxo_vads_subscription`
        # Où la transaction a réussi
        WHERE orders_3.`status` = 2
            # qui soit après la campagne de pâques
            AND orders_3.`engagement` = 'M' 
            AND `orders_3`.`gxo_means` = 'CB'
        GROUP BY YEAR(orders_3.date), MONTH(orders_3.date)
```

Me devuelve:

```
...
1/5/2021, 8:04    86
1/6/2021, 4:54    36
```

[Aqui esta el resultado y el Fiddle relacionado](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed044f1/2/0)

Hay un problema: los resultados que me devuelve la division del `count_initialization/count_first_recurrent` al segundo parcen ser demasiado altos cuando lo comparo con la media:

```
...
1/4/2021, 1:10    664,25
11/5/2021, 1:10   662,75
7/6/2021, 1:10    610,75
```

Significa que hay 6 veces más iniciaciones que dieron lugar a al menos un pago que iniciaciones, lo cual es imposible.

Aqui esta el script para obtener la media de `0,74`:

```
SELECT (count_first_recurrent/count_initialization) FROM
    (
        (SELECT count(distinct `orders`.`gxo_vads_subscription`) count_first_recurrent
        FROM `orders`
        WHERE `orders`.`engagement` = 'R'
           AND `orders`.`status` = 2 AND `orders`.`gxo_means` = 'CB') as a,
           
        (SELECT count(distinct `orders`.`gxo_vads_subscription`) count_initialization
        FROM `orders`
        WHERE `orders`.`engagement` = 'M'
           AND `orders`.`status` = 2 AND `orders`.`gxo_means` = 'CB') AS b
   )
```

[.](https://metabase.data.hozana.org/question#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_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-PSBvcmRlcnNfMS5kYXRlICsgSU5URVJWQUwgMzAgREFZXG4gICAgR1JPVVAgQlkgWUVBUihvcmRlcnNfMi5kYXRlKSwgTU9OVEgob3JkZXJzXzIuZGF0ZSlcbiAgICBcbi0tIFNFTEVDVCBvcmRlcnNfMy5kYXRlLCBDT1VOVChESVNUSU5DVCBvcmRlcnNfMy5gZ3hvX3ZhZHNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uYCkgY291bnRfaW5pdGlhbGl6YXRpb25cbi0tICAgICAgICAgRlJPTSBgb3JkZXJzYCBBUyBvcmRlcnNfM1xuLS0gICAgICAgICAjIE_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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo como dice @david-jp: "Las primeras transacciones son M y las recurrentes R".

Un opción utilizando `LEFT JOIN`.

En la subquery `m` obtengo la fecha y el identificador de la suscripción de todas las órdenes con `engagement = 'M'` (primer pago), luego hago un `LEFT JOIN` con la subquery `r` (pagos mensuales) que retorna los identificadores de las suscripciones con `engagement = 'R'` y la última fecha en que pagó (agrupando por el identificador de la suscripción). Vinculando por el identificador de la suscripción y por r.max_date que tiene que ser mayor que el último día del mes en que realizó el primer pago. Si hay matched significa que hubo al menos un pago en algún momento a partir del mes siguiente, caso contrario que no y `count(r.gxo_vads_subscription)` será nulo.

Luego agrupo por año y mes; cuento la cantidad de iniciaciones de cada mes `count(m.gxo_vads_subscription)`, de esas iniciaciones la cantidad que volvieron a pagar a partir del mes siguiente `count(r.gxo_vads_subscription)`, y utilizando ambos valores calculo el porcentaje de reincidentes (que volvieron a pagar en por lo menos algún mes posterior).

```
SELECT YEAR(m.`date`) AS anio, MONTH(m.`date`) AS mes,
        count(m.`gxo_vads_subscription`) AS cantidad_iniciaciones,
        count(r.`gxo_vads_subscription`) AS cantidad_reincidieron,
        count(r.`gxo_vads_subscription`) / count(m.`gxo_vads_subscription`) * 100 AS porcentaje
        
FROM (SELECT `date`, `gxo_vads_subscription`
      FROM orders
      WHERE `engagement` = 'M') m
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `gxo_vads_subscription`, MAX(`date`) AS max_date
           FROM orders
           WHERE `engagement` = 'R'
           GROUP BY `gxo_vads_subscription`) r ON m.`gxo_vads_subscription` = r.`gxo_vads_subscription` 
                                                  AND LAST_DAY(m.`date`) < r.max_date
GROUP BY YEAR(m.`date`), MONTH(m.`date`);
```

En este caso el resultado es:

| año | mes | cantidad_iniciaciones | cantidad_reincidieron | porcentaje |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 3 | 36 | 21 | 58.3333 |

Si quisieras obtener los que volvieron pagar pero incluyendo los que volvieron a pagar solo en el mismo mes del primer pago (al menos por el momento), tendrías que quitar del `ON`: `AND LAST_DAY(m.date) < r.max_date` y el resultado sería:

| año | mes | cantidad_iniciaciones | cantidad_reincidieron | porcentaje |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 3 | 36 | 28 | 77.7778 |

Answer (score 1):

La solución que te propongo es:

```
SELECT *,ROUND(n_fidelizaciones/n_promociones*100) efectividad
  FROM (
    SELECT YEAR(fecha) ejercicio,MONTH(fecha) mes,
      COUNT(*) n_fidelizaciones FROM (
        SELECT gxo_vads_subscription, COUNT(*),
          GROUP_CONCAT(engagement ORDER BY fecha) engs,
          MIN(fecha) fecha
          FROM orders
          GROUP BY 1
          HAVING COUNT(*)>1  
      ) c1 GROUP BY 1,2  
  ) c3 JOIN (
    SELECT YEAR(fecha) ejercicio,MONTH(fecha) mes,
      COUNT(DISTINCT gxo_vads_subscription) n_promociones
      FROM orders
      WHERE engagement='M'
      GROUP BY 1,2  
  ) c4 USING(ejercicio,mes);
```

Que, para los datos que has colgado en Fiddle, se obtiene una efectividad del 78% en el único mes en el que inicias transacciones, que será cuando hayas hecho la campaña:

```
+-----------+------+------------------+---------------+-------------+
| ejercicio | mes  | n_fidelizaciones | n_promociones | efectividad |
+-----------+------+------------------+---------------+-------------+
|      2020 |    3 |               28 |            36 |          78 |
+-----------+------+------------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Para llegar a este resultado, he modificado tu campo `date` de la tabla `orders` que originalmente era un `VARCHAR(19)` para convertirlo en `DATETIME` así:

```
UPDATE orders set date=REPLACE(date,'T',' ');
ALTER TABLE orders CHANGE date fecha datetime;
```

Analizado un poco tu tabla con esta consulta:

```
SELECT gxo_vads_subscription, COUNT(*),
  GROUP_CONCAT(engagement ORDER BY fecha) engs,
  MIN(fecha) fecha
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 4;
```

He podido observar que:

```
+-----------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| gxo_vads_subscription       | COUNT(*) | engs    | fecha               |
+-----------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| 20200301k8N7D8              |        1 | M       | 2020-03-01 09:01:35 |
| pm_1GHqH0HlzFjSGyGX9VmpyS8X |        1 | M       | 2020-03-01 12:47:00 |
| pm_1GIJRaHlzFjSGyGXNQbLTXs2 |        1 | M       | 2020-03-02 19:55:51 |
| 20200303sjl2XH              |        4 | M,R,R,R | 2020-03-03 19:30:35 |
| 20200305xNT4I6              |        4 | M,R,R,R | 2020-03-05 15:02:39 |
| pm_1GJNqxHlzFjSGyGXyFmCH5eB |        1 | M       | 2020-03-05 18:50:17 |
| 20200305FgtLyx              |        4 | M,R,R,R | 2020-03-05 22:45:22 |
| 20200306pyhtvp              |        4 | M,R,R,R | 2020-03-06 15:17:59 |
| 20200306ErguOR              |        4 | M,R,R,R | 2020-03-06 16:13:53 |
| 20200308N9oz9A              |        3 | M,R,R   | 2020-03-08 09:47:16 |
| 20200309VclhYo              |        3 | M,R,R   | 2020-03-09 11:00:50 |
| 20200310gt738p              |        2 | M,R     | 2020-03-10 08:40:14 |
| 20200310sUMwbJ              |        3 | M,R,R   | 2020-03-10 16:16:29 |
| 20200311uPF742              |        3 | M,R,R   | 2020-03-11 07:50:05 |
| 20200311XJq357              |        2 | M,R     | 2020-03-11 08:31:09 |
| 20200311wPvhZL              |        2 | M,R     | 2020-03-11 09:16:44 |
| 20200311T83B6v              |        3 | M,R,R   | 2020-03-11 09:38:19 |
| pm_1GLQjwHlzFjSGyGXBWHsORQ5 |        1 | M       | 2020-03-11 10:18:49 |
| 20200311YszBmU              |        3 | M,R,R   | 2020-03-11 12:45:07 |
| 20200311EnLVIa              |        3 | M,R,R   | 2020-03-11 13:21:45 |
| pm_1GLhlXHlzFjSGyGXX3zH1kH2 |        1 | M       | 2020-03-12 04:28:54 |
| 20200312zSP7z7              |        3 | M,R,R   | 2020-03-12 05:37:24 |
| pm_1GM0A7HlzFjSGyGXsntlIbBC |        1 | M       | 2020-03-13 00:07:45 |
| 20200313PGmDBI              |        3 | M,R,R   | 2020-03-13 09:13:59 |
| pm_1GMGNjHlzFjSGyGXN79NAZxF |        1 | M       | 2020-03-13 17:27:59 |
| 20200313qoG6Kl              |        3 | M,R,R   | 2020-03-13 19:27:02 |
| 20200315ElRYT5              |        2 | M,R     | 2020-03-15 23:48:43 |
| 20200316SY3wI9              |        2 | M,R     | 2020-03-16 11:01:32 |
| 20200316I3bizB              |        3 | M,R,R   | 2020-03-16 13:58:30 |
| 20200317PQpHc2              |        3 | M,R,R   | 2020-03-17 09:21:44 |
| 20200317whfClj              |        3 | M,R,R   | 2020-03-17 12:05:52 |
| 20200318xKCNh1              |        2 | M,R     | 2020-03-18 04:10:13 |
| 20200318ljefmy              |        3 | M,R,R   | 2020-03-18 12:33:34 |
| 20200318fnTJuk              |        3 | M,R,R   | 2020-03-18 16:57:08 |
| 20200319JlkZJc              |        3 | M,R,R   | 2020-03-19 03:58:42 |
| 20200319j6WqHi              |        2 | M,R     | 2020-03-19 11:42:51 |
+-----------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
```

- Las primeras transacciones son `M` y las recurrentes `R`, y creo que en tus intentos lo interpretas al revés.
- Todas las `R` vienen de una `M`, por lo que la consulta se te simplifica bastante y no hace falta conectar por `gxo_vads_subscription`, sino únicamente agrupar por éste y conectar por meses para obtener el retorno de cada una de las iniciaciones `M` que hayas podido realizar en diferentes meses.
- Es posible que haya malinterpretado alguna de tus indicaciones, pero es lo que he podido deducir de tus intentos. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios y le damos una vuelta más. Aún se puede sacar más información de esta tabla...

Comment: Gracias para tua respuesta, tienes razon, las primeras transacciones son M y las recurrentes son R, todas las R vienen de una M

Comment: Por tanto, si hay `R`, es que ya ha habido éxito... ¿necesitas saber cuánto tarda en llegar ese éxito?

Comment: No, no necesito saber cuándo llegará este éxito por el momento

Comment: Entonces, ¿la consulta cuadra con lo que esperabas?

Comment: Absolutamente, pero me cuesta aceptarlo porque por un lado no encuentro los mismos resultados que nachospiu (en los datos reales [los tuyos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhvFx.png) muestra 47% y 65% en junio y julio, [los suyos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaZaf.png) muestra 43,1% y 9,3% respectivamente) y por otro lado me parece más difícil de entender y por tanto de modificar que nachospiu. Pero no es tan malo porque releyendo línea por línea lo consigo.

Comment: Por ejemplo tengo problemas entender GROUP BY 1 (o 1,2)

Comment: Él parece que tiene en cuenta cuándo llega al éxito, por eso propone dos resultados diferentes, dependiendo si quieres medir el éxito en el mismo mes o en los siguientes. Para salir de dudas tendrás que contar manualmente y quedarte con la solución que coincida con cómo lo haces tú...

Comment: `GROUP BY 1`, funciona igual que `ORDER BY 1`, agrupan y ordenan por el primer campo que aparece tras el `SELECT`, vienen en el manual de MySQL